# Session Struts2 SSL

Tags: struts2

I have created a Login Application with struts 2 and integrated with SSL. When I click on the back button after logging out, I am still able to see the page though it shows session expired when I try to perform any action on the page. **But, when I refresh the page, I am able to perform all the actions on the page. I have removed the cookies using an Interceptor on the event of LogOut.** Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Do you use some security framework?

Comment: Perhaps the page is being cached by the browser? You may want to set a Cache-Control header in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not much information that you give us here.

I think the problem might stem from the URL of the page that you are refreshing. Please take a look at that and what action that URLs gets called, and all the GET and POST data that is appended when reloading the page. You might want to use a debugger for this. Maybe this information regenerates the cookie or the logged-in information in the session.

You can use the SessionAware interceptor to store data based on the uses's session. If you don't find the error, you can put a boolean loggedIn flag into the session, check at the beginning of your actions if the user is really logged in, and set the value to false when the user logs out.